# OpenCV: Failed to correctly use LineIterator, gives meaningless values

Tags: c++, opencv

I am experiencing a very strange behavior in my following program. I am basically iterating through 2 points on an image and collecting all the pixel values in a variable `linePixels`.

I pass the two points from `main()` correctly, since I verified before passing to `IterateLine()` and inside `IterateLine()`. I saw both are equal.

But The `linePixels` I always get as 114.

But If I hardcode the points (start and end ), inside `IterateLine()`, then I get meaningful values.

I am not able to understand what wrong here ? Something is there which I am missing.

Please help.

```
void IterateLine( const Mat& image, vector<ushort>& linePixels, Point p2, Point p1, int *count1 )
{
     //Am I getting correct image? 
    cout<<"Pixel values in image in IterateLine"<<endl; 

    cout<<Mat(image)<<endl; //Yes this shows meaningful values indeed 


 //hard coding pixel coordinates for debugging. Prints meaningful pixel values at end  
p1.x=32;
p1.y=66;

p2.x=230;
p2.y=86;

//but If I do not use hard coded values as above, then it always prints 114 



//Am I getting correct pixel coordinates? Let us print   
cout<<"First coordinates received in IterateLine()  are given below"<<endl;
cout<<p1.x<<'\t'<<p1.y<<endl; 

cout<<"Second coordinates received in IterateLine()  are given below"<<endl;
cout<<p2.y<<'\t'<<p2.y<<endl;

//The above indeed prints meaningful coordinates, but only when pixel values are hard coded   

    LineIterator it(image, p2,p1, 8);

    for(int i = 0; i < it.count; i++, it++){
        linePixels.push_back(image.at<ushort>(it.pos()));
    }

   *count1=it.count; 


    cout<<"No. of pixels in IterateLLine"<<endl;

    cout<<count1[0]<<endl; 


cout<<"pixel values in  IterateLine are"<<endl;

    for(int i=0;i<count1[0];i++)

    {

        cout<<linePixels[i]<<endl;
    }



}
```

**Output when pixel coordinates are hard coded:**

```
First coordinates passed to IterateLine() in main() are given below
  10     15 
Second coordinates passed to IterateLine() in main() are given below
  200    150 
First coordinates received in IterateLine()  are given below
32      66
Second coordinates received in IterateLine()  are given below
230     86
No. of pixels in IterateLLine
199
pixel values in  IterateLine are
42405
41634
36237
34952
43947
26471
26985
27756
29555
35723
23901
24415
38807
25186
25186
42662
29041
29812
42405
34438
35209
42148
35980
36751
38807
28013
```

**Output when pixel coordinates are not hardcoded**

```
First coordinates passed to IterateLine() in main() are given below
96      56
Second coordinates passed to IterateLine() in main() are given below
192     160
First coordinates received in IterateLine()  are given below
 96      56
Second coordinates received in IterateLine()  are given below
 192     160
No. of pixels in IterateLLine
204
pixel values in  IterateLine are
114
114
114
114
114
114
114
114
114
114
114
114
114
```

My `main()` is as shown below:

```
int main()

{

     Mat img = imread("sir.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYCOLOR | CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH);


 vector<Point> points1;

 vector<ushort>linePixels;

 //Draw the line, and collect end and final point coordinates in points1 

      drawline(img, points1); 

//now check the collected points

cout<<"First coordinates passed to IterateLine() in main() are given below"<<endl;
cout<<points1[0].x<<'\t'<<points1[0].y<<endl; 


cout<<"Second coordinates passed to IterateLine() in main() are given below"<<endl;
cout<<points1[1].x<<'\t'<<points1[1].y<<endl; 


IterateLine( img, linePixels, points1[1], points1[0], t );   

return 0 ; 
}
```

**Update**

This is my drawline()

```
void drawline( Mat image, std::vector<Point>& points )

{

cv::namedWindow("Output Window");

cv::setMouseCallback("Output Window", onMouse, (void*)&points);
int X1=0, Y1=0, X2=0, Y2=0; 




while(1)
{
    cv::imshow("Output Window", image);

    if (points.size() > 1) //we have 2 points
    {

        for (auto it = points.begin(); it != points.end(); ++it)
        {


        }


        break;
    }
    waitKey(10);


}


 X1=points[0].x; 
X2=points[1].x; 


Y1=points[0].y; 
Y2=points[1].y; 

     //   Draw a line 

line(image,  Point(X1, Y1), Point(X2, Y2), 'r',  2, 8 );

cv::imshow("Output Window", image);


//exit image window 
while(true)
    {
        char c = cv::waitKey(10);
        if(c == 'q')
            break;
    }


destroyWindow("Output Window");




}
```

**Update 2**

As pointed out by @berak actually I am iterating over the line that I have drawn. This line has a single color and that is why I get 114. So I must make the line transparent to IterateLine() (but visible to human beings). Any suggestions how to achieve this?

**Update 3**

I solved this my reading a the original image once again in a new Mat object img1:

```
    Mat img = imread("sir.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYCOLOR | CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH);
    drawline(img, points1);
    Mat img1 = imread("sir.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYCOLOR | CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH);
    IterateLine( img1, linePixels, points1[1], points1[0], t );
```

But this is not very efficient method, so I am still looking for best way of doing this.

Comment: @berak you mean I am getting pixel values of the 'line' that I have drawn?

Comment: @berak So how do I make this line transparent so that IterateLine() do not see it? And only human being see that line

Comment: @berak Kindly see my update , I have shown my drawline()

Comment: @berak The two points that I click , are stored in vector<Point>& points, and then I use it in my IterateLine();

Comment: Instead of reading your image twice, you can just copy it. It will be more efficient than reading tzice the data on the disk. 

Beware of the different functions for copying Mat, though. Some only copy the headers and still refer to the same underlying data, some really copy the headers AND the data in the new Mat object.